# Coping with mud in the face

Tags: mountain-bike, glasses, protection

I am not talking about [swimming in mud](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3634/mountain-biking-how-to-ride-in-mud). Just a damp trail or even wet pavement - and some modest speed - and the front tire function switches from steering the bike to throwing mud precisely directed at the rider's face.

Without protective gear, the mud and gravel projectiles hit the eyes at unpredictable moments and the chance of loss of steering is significant.

With clear sunglasses, the lens become stained in a couple of minutes and impair vision. I am reluctant to brush them with my glove as I reckon this would:

- be not very effective, only transforming the mud droplets into a solid film of mud and sand
- scratch the lens badly after several tens of scrapes.

How do downhill riders cope with this? Does the full-face helmet protect the mask in some way? Do they apply [anti-water coating](http://www.tashev.bg/shop/product_info.php?language=en&idarticles=1316) on the mask? Do they install some hardy front fender? Or do they just live with it?

In the [2011 Megavelanche](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfwTlTxhbG0), the guy has the camera behind his mask. It got only several drops of dirty water during the entire race, regardless of him riding through snow, mud, water, dirt, gravel. How is this possible, and why do my glasses look like shit when I am touring over asphalt and it rained yesterday?

Comment: Again, too many questions in a single question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do downhill riders cope with this?

1. With a [front fender](http://www.moredirt.com/photos/84240.jpg) or with a mud guard such as [this](http://reviews.mtbr.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/neoguardxc_1.jpg).
2. With goggles which use [disposable tear off lenses](http://p.vitalmtb.com/photos/products/4186/photos/8703/s1600_Iris_DH_white_01.jpg) or the ones with a reel of fresh len material which is pulled via a string or [via bluetooth or something](http://ep1.pinkbike.org/p4pb7841870/p4pb7841870.jpg).

> Does the full-face helmet protect the mask in some way?

Probably not.

> Do they apply anti-water coating on the mask?

No

> Do they install some hardy front fender?

In really muddy conditions it's almost mandatory.

> Or do they just live with it?

Nobody likes mud in their eyes or mouth.

Comment: k. ordered a [fender](http://muckynutz-bg.com/?product=bender-fender-xl)

Comment: You'd be surprised how much a full face helmet protects from the splatter. Depends on how far the front sticks out though.

Answer (score -1):

I use a Stealth Shield carbon fiber mudguard from Cycle Armour (order at www.cycle-armour.com). It seems to remove about 85% of the dirt from my eyes (more on straights and less on twisty parts). It weighs nothing, looks good, and is very aerodynamic. It actually automatically adjusts if thick mud is encountered.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. If you are in any way affiliated with this product, [you must declare your affiliation](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) within the body of your answer. Whether or not you are affiliated, it would be good if you could give reason why this fender is better than any other option. From what I can see, it doesn't look any different than anything else on the market. As it stands, your answer is likely to get downvoted, flagged as spam, and possibly deleted.